# What to do about the tags phrase/phrases/expressions/idioms/proverbs?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

These tags are all used similarly:

- [phrase](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase)/[phrases](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases)
- [expressions](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions)
- [idioms](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms)
- [proverbs](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proverbs)

What should be done about them?

Comment: you missed adage, aphorism, axiom....

Comment: @adolf: I'd enjoy a rigorous, axiom-based German language.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that [idioms](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms) and [proverbs](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proverbs) are clearly defined, and that we should impose their correct usage by retagging and comments. The tags [expressions](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expressions), [phrase](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase) and [phrases](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases) are more diffuse, so the two other tags should be preferred over these.

And just to make my understanding of *idioms* and *proverbs* explicit I'll quote *www.thefreedictionary.com*: an idiom is "a speech form [...] that is peculiar to itself grammatically or cannot be understood from the individual meanings of its elements", but a proverb is "a short pithy saying in frequent and widespread use that expresses a basic truth or practical precept."

Therefore *"ins Fettnäpfchen treten"* is an idiom, while *"Morgenstund’ hat Gold im Mund"* is a proverb.

Comment: Do you suggest that we retag all the expressions/phrase/phrases questions to idioms or proverbs?

Comment: If we did it with old questions everything would float to the top, but for questions posed from now on we can do it, yes. But do everything that is tagged with expressions, phrase or phrases really fit into the categories idioms or proverbs? The phrase "Grüß Gott" is neither idiom nor proverb, nicht wahr?

Comment: I'd say keep [idioms], [proverbs] and [phrases]